# Delete the [spike] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Can I delete the [spike] tag? There are only [9 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spike) with it and 1 follower.

It seems to be used for four things:

- [In TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249969/why-are-tdd-spikes-called-spikes)
- [In version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282434/in-source-control-terminology-what-is-a-spike)
- [For graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169081/what-does-spikeline-in-a-chart-mean)
- For performance issues (the other 6 questions)

Comment: Hmm, if they are valid and descriptive terms in TDD and Version Control, then perhaps not. But with just 9 tags, they can't be all that important... (For graphs and performance issues I would nuke them personally).

Comment: In version control, this is what is most commonly called a tag, so if anything the question should have the tag [tag:tags]. However, the asker didn't know the meaning so wouldn't have used [tag:tags]. This question doesn't need a [tag:spike] or [tag:tags] tag. I don't know if the TDD term is common enough to warrant a tag ([tag:tdd-spike]?); given that there's only one question, presumably not.

Comment: That was my reasoning too. If nobody tells me otherwise I will remove it tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted [spike] from all questions.